# Proper way to add an array to a $_SESSION variable that already contains arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the proper way to add an array to a $_SESSION variable that already contains arrays in PHP?

For example I have a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['test']
```

Then I do this:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array('sample' => '1', 'sample2' => 2);
```

THEN, I come back to this session data at a later date. How would I add another array to $_SESSION['test'] without destroying what was already in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the size of current value, if it's 1 (means there is one array), then make a new array, which contains previous value from `test` and add the new value. Then change `test` value to this new two dimension array.

Would look something like that:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array('sample' => '1', 'sample2' => 2);

if(is_array($_SESSION['test']) && sizeof($_SESSION['test'] == 1){
    $newValue = array();
    $newValue[] = $_SESSION['test'];
    $newValue[] = $yourOtherArray;
    $_SESSION['test'] = $newValue;
}
```

Fast and simple. Oh, not so sure if this is "proper" way.

Comment: Seems like a whole lot of extra and unnecessary work given that `array_merge` function. Although, testing if it is an array is probably a good idea.

Comment: But `array_merge()` will merge them together, where this will keep em seperated.

Comment: Yea, I get you. I guess it all depends on what the OP meant, as he was sort of unclear on that / could be taken multiple ways. It would also depend on the format of the "new array" if it is multi-dimensional or not.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean add another array element?

If so, you would do:

```
$_SESSION['test']['sample3'] = 3;
```

But if not, then it sounds like `array_merge` is your ticket.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can use [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/array_merge) to merge the arrays.

```
$new_array = array('x' => array('extra')));
$_SESSION['test'] = is_array($_SESSION['test'])?array_merge($_SESSION['test'], $new_array):$new_array;
```

**EDIT**

Updated to do an `is_array` check, if it is an array it is merged, else it is set to the `$new_array`.